# Swift iOS 17 Audio Drops Out When Setting AudioSession Category to .playAndRecord

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

I am creating an app where you can record a video and listen to music in the background. At the top of my viewDidLoad I set the AVAudioSession Category to .playAndRecord

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
AVCaptureSession().automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
    try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch {
    print("error trying to record and play audio")
}
```

However when I do this the audio cuts out for a second or less at app open and app close. I would like the audio to continue playing and not cutout. Is there anything I can do to ensure the audio continues to play?

I have tried moving when `AVCaptureSession().automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false` is set to see if that improves the issues but I am not seeing any improvement.

I have tried to set the playback category as well and that has not fixed the problem.